# Pass a parameter in a hidden field for embedded chat?

Tags: api, chat, pre-chat

We currently have a visual force page for a custom chat solution. In this solution we use hidden fields to pass parameters from the .com site where the chat is hosted to salesforce. Specifically populating a field on the case object that labels where the chat originated from since we have the chat hosted on multiple locations.

Now I am looking to move to an imbedded chat solution so that the chat resizes correctly for mobile web.

How can I similarly edit the code snippet to achieve the same for imbedded chat? Without showing the field to the chasitor?